# VB: adding object to a tabcontrol tab which doiesnt exist at this time

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

i want to add a tabcontrol tab by pressing on a button:

```
    Dim inp As String
    inp = TextBox6.Text
    TabControl2.TabPages.Add(inp)
```

and when i open this tabpage some object should be already created like a button and a textbox, etc.
i havent found any type of onload events for a tabpage so i tried to add this with:

```
TabPage8.Controls.Add(New Button())
```

tabpage8 would be the name of the new created tabpage but like vb already told me, i cant add objects to a tabpage which doesnt exist at that time.

is there any way i can do that or have you any other ideas which could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is close.  Try the following:

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      TabControl2.TabPages.Add("Test")
      Dim tp = TabControl2.TabPages(TabControl2.TabPages.Count - 1)
      Dim b = New Button()
      b.Text = "My Button"
      tp.Controls.Add(b)

      AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf MyButton_Click
   End Sub

   Private Sub MyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      MessageBox.Show("MyButton clicked")
   End Sub
```

This code grabs the last page added and adds a button to it.  It also configures the button as needed and adds an event handler.

Comment: thank you for the fast response - but how can i edit this new created button? i mean where can i specify what the button has to do when i press it?